# magento2 reindex is very slow

Tags: performance, magento2, reindex

my magento2 website have about 180000 skus in the store now.

I added products by inserting data directly by sql statements.
I visit the products all normally on the frontend.
But today I found that some reindex operations very slow, for example,

`bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute`

or

`bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`

It will take about more than 3 hours to finish.
Is this performance normal? Is it possible to just reindex the new or modified products?

The Envs on my website:
magento2  2.4.1,
php 7.4
mysql 5.7,
elastic search(7.x)

Thank you very much.

Comment: centos7 , cpu 4 cores, ram 16G

Comment: I think the performance of indexing may rely on many factors, for example on all other processes that your machine is sharing. Then it can depend on configuration - php, mysql, elasticsearch. And then it depends on the hardware - especially the type of disks but not only. It would be better to run it on some dedicated, well configured machine. Definitely there should be some information in your question about the mentioned above factors since your concern is about the time on this machine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Despite hardware, operating system and server configuration you may run indexer from CLI once and then set this indexer in

1. `update on schedule` mode
2. `update on save` mode.

The first one is recommended since indexer is running every minute and it only indexing again invalidated SKUs. The second option is rebuilding index for given SKU just after saving the product but it may be problematic when multiple people have admin access and are working at the same time.